# I can't round it on 2 decimals

Tags: javascript, numbers, decimal

I'm trying to give the outcome of this script 2 decimals. They all actually already have 2 decimals, but when I add the last 2 together (35.75 + 16.06), I get    €51.629999999999995 as the output.

Here is my script;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function bereken() {
        var total = 0;
        if (document.forms[0].boek1.checked)  {
          total += 27.74;
        }
        if (document.forms[0].boek2.checked) {
          total += 26.13;
        }
        if (document.forms[0].boek3.checked) {
          total += 35.57;
        }
        if (document.forms[0].boek4.checked) {
          total += 16.06;
        }
        totalP = "€" + total
        document.forms[0].total.value = totalP; 
      } 
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="checkbox" name="boek1">Boek 1<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="boek2">Boek 2<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="boek3">Boek 3<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="boek4">Boek 4<br>
      <div><input type="button" value="Totaal" onclick="bereken()" /><br><br>
        <input type="text" value="€" name="total" size="5" />
    </form>
  </body>
```

Does any of you know what I did wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: That's a wrong HTML BTW: `<! DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round):

```
document.forms[0].total.value = Math.round(parseFloat(totalP.substr(1)) * 100)/100;
```

**Working Preview**

[image]

There are other ways to do it too. You can also use `.toFixed(n)`:

```
document.forms[0].total.value = parseFloat(totalP.substr(1)).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: OP is asking _it on 2 decimals_

Comment: @RayonDabre `*100/100` will give two decimal places right? Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: @Praveen, Input is `€51.629999999999995`

Comment: How about this: `var input=51.629999999999995;
var final=input.toFixed(2);
alert(final);`

Comment: @AmirAkbulut Any updates from your side? Does it work or not?

Comment: @AmirAkbulut Replace this line: `document.forms[0].total.value = totalP;`

Comment: @AmirAkbulut Can't you compare the code and replace? Didn't you do this code yourself?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

checkout the function decimalAdjust. Works pretty well

```
function decimalAdjust(type, value, exp) {
    // If the exp is undefined or zero...
    if (typeof exp === 'undefined' || +exp === 0) {
      return Math[type](value);
    }
    value = +value;
    exp = +exp;
    // If the value is not a number or the exp is not an integer...
    if (isNaN(value) || !(typeof exp === 'number' && exp % 1 === 0)) {
      return NaN;
    }
    // Shift
    value = value.toString().split('e');
    value = Math[type](+(value[0] + 'e' + (value[1] ? (+value[1] - exp) : -exp)));
    // Shift back
    value = value.toString().split('e');
    return +(value[0] + 'e' + (value[1] ? (+value[1] + exp) : exp));
  }
```